# Unidentified issues with bluetooth on Ubuntu 20.04 - unable to connect airpods

Tags: bluetooth

To sum up my problem, I was trying to connect my airpods as headphones to my computer but my computer does not even detect my airpods as a device to connect to. Switching ControllerMode to either "Dual", "le" or "bredr" in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf did not help solving the problem.

I started to look at forums, entered a few commands to get info and got the following outputs with errors at the last lines Bluetooth: hci0: ... :

```
@latitude5400:~$ uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth
Linux latitude5400 5.4.0-81-generic #91-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 15 19:09:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:4030]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
--
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V [8086:15be] (rev 30)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V [1028:08b8]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5539 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[87364.768825] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
[88846.069775] Bluetooth: hci0: failed to restart LE scan: status 31
[88846.073726] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[89326.411054] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
bluetooth             548864  37 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
```

```
@latitude5400:~$ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-09-17 10:42:11 CEST; 30min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 17114 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18923)
     Memory: 2.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─17114 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

sept. 17 10:42:11 latitude5400 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
sept. 17 10:42:11 latitude5400 bluetoothd[17114]: Starting SDP server
sept. 17 10:42:11 latitude5400 bluetoothd[17114]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
sept. 17 10:42:11 latitude5400 bluetoothd[17114]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.69 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
sept. 17 10:42:11 latitude5400 bluetoothd[17114]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.69 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
sept. 17 10:42:20 latitude5400 bluetoothd[17114]: SET_CONFIGURATION request rejected: Configuration not supported (41)
sept. 17 10:48:32 latitude5400 bluetoothd[17114]: Unable to get connect data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
sept. 17 10:48:33 latitude5400 bluetoothd[17114]: connect error: Connection refused (111)
sept. 17 10:48:33 latitude5400 bluetoothd[17114]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for 4C:1D:96:E2:43:47: Device or resource busy
sept. 17 10:48:35 latitude5400 bluetoothd[17114]: connect error: Connection refused (111)
```

```
@latitude5400:~$ dpkg -l |grep blue
ii  blueman                                    2.1.2-1ubuntu0.2                      amd64        Graphical bluetooth manager
ii  bluez                                      5.53-0ubuntu3.3                       amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-btsco                                1:0.50-0ubuntu7                       amd64        Bluez Bluetooth SCO tool
ii  bluez-cups                                 5.53-0ubuntu3.3                       amd64        Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS
ii  bluez-dbg                                  5.53-0ubuntu3.3                       amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons (with debugging symbols)
ii  bluez-hcidump                              5.53-0ubuntu3.3                       amd64        Analyses Bluetooth HCI packets
ii  bluez-obexd                                5.53-0ubuntu3.3                       amd64        bluez obex daemon
ii  bluez-tests                                5.53-0ubuntu3.3                       amd64        BlueZ test tools and scripts
ii  bluez-tools                                2.0~20170911.0.7cb788c-2build1        amd64        Set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices for linux
ii  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0:amd64            3.34.3-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Introspection data for GnomeBluetooth
ii  gnome-bluetooth                            3.34.3-0ubuntu1                       amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools
ii  libbluetooth3:amd64                        5.53-0ubuntu3.3                       amd64        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  libbluetooth3-dbg                          5.53-0ubuntu3.3                       amd64        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack with debugging symbols
ii  libgnome-bluetooth13:amd64                 3.34.3-0ubuntu1                       amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools - support library
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11                 amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
```

and finally

```
@latitude5400:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

.
As additional information, I can connect to other devices (such as an Iphone or speakers) and use them properly. My end goal is connecting my earpods, but any information about where could the problem comes from, if there is compatibility issue between my kernel and my bluetooth device or anything would be very useful.

Additional info about my system config:
System: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS - 64 bits
GNOME version: 3.36.8
Kernel version: 5.4.0-81-generic

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Most systems of your type run the 5.8 or 5.11 kernel is there a reason you do not?

Comment: I don't know why, I think that my sys admin chose the configuration, I can ask him if you want.

Comment: Do not ask fro me ask for yourself. The newer kernel may fix the problem.

Comment: Ok maybe. I'll give it a try. Thanks for the suggestion !